# Addshape in cell corner

Tags: excel, shapes, vba

Hi I need to add shape dynamically to cell corner D12 (left, down) 
here's my code

```
  Set textRectangle = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, Range("D13").Left, Range("D13").Top, 20, 20)

textRectangle.name = "test shape"
' add your text
textRectangle.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Your"

' fill the shape with the rgb color of your choice
textRectangle.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(220, 105, 0)
```

with this result : [image]

and here's the result I want to have
[image]

I am reshapping the circle after creating it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may need to consider the radius of the shape as well while adding it.

**Code:**

```
Sub add_shape()

    Dim textRectangle As Shape
    Dim radius As Integer
    radius = 20
    Set textRectangle = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, (Range("D13").Left - radius / 2), _
                        Range("D13").Top - radius / 2, radius, radius)

End Sub
```

Also (for future reference), you can make use of `Range("A1").Width` and `Range("A1").Height` properties for other object manipulation :)

HTH ;)

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried it and it's not in the center of the corner, am I missing something ?

Comment: I tried your code, then I tried my code who is mess but give me the good position :   Set textRectangle = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, (Range("D12").Left) - 10, (Range("D12").Top) + 89, 10, 10)

Comment: I made reference to `D13` not `D12`, that may be the difference! :) To this code work you should reference the bottom cell (`D13` in the pictures) and then apply the `- radius / 2` offset both horizontal and vertical. Can you post a picture with the result of my code please?  (Note: in my PC it is working)

Comment: OK sir I will do it now

Comment: Are you resizing the columns or rows after adding the shape? That may be the issue since adding the oval shape with the same horizontal and vertical radius will result in a circle :) If you resize the columns or rows after placing the shape it will get reshaped.

Comment: If I dont resize for exemple group 20 or group 21 will be group2 (0 or 1 is hided):  textRectangles.name = "Groups " & i
    textRectangles.TextFrame.Characters.Text = i
    textRectangle.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    textRectangles.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(220, 105, 0)

Comment: So that's the problem! You should give a greater radius while creating the shape, otherwise the circle will be streched in order to display all of the text :) You can previously check the size of the text and change the radius accordling to avoid a big circle with few letters.

Comment: Example: `If Len(text) < 6 Then radius = 20 Else radius = 40 End If`

Comment: the length text is an integer from 1 to 99 , I will try your solution, thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: If you need more help just ask ;) In the meantime edit your answer to reflect the changes you made (remove the extra picture or write that you are reshapping the circle after creating it). If you are happy with the solution I would ask you could accept the answer :)

Comment: You are the only person that helped me, other people gave me minus 2 for a similar question, I will edit my question and Thank you again